# How to allocate a buffer suitable to hold an object of type T (which may be over-aligned, may have operator new, etc)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In a library I'm working on, I need to allocate space that will eventually be passed to placement-`new` to construct objects of arbitrary types. Those instances will be returned to the caller code, and need to behave properly with the user just writing `delete t;` or having whatever `unique_ptr` analog they're using do it for them.

The naive approach of `T *t = new char[sizeof(T)]` has at least a few problems that I've run noticed:

1. If `T` is declared with an `alignas` specifier, then I can't manually pad the buffer accordingly, because the resulting address won't be the right one to pass to `delete`
2. The expression `delete t;` will be a mismatch between `operator delete()` and `operator delete[]()`
3. If the code declares a custom `T::operator new` and `T::operator delete` (for memory pooling, segregation, tracking, whatever), then we neglect to call the allocator, and mis-match on the call to the de-allocator

Seemingly much better is `T *t = std::allocator<T>::allocate(1)`, which addresses the alignment concern in point 1 and the scalar/array mismatch concern in point 2. However, per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate), it always calls the global `::operator new`. Thus, it would still fail on point 3.

Is the reference wrong? Is there some slightly higher-level routine in the standard library I'm missing that does the right thing? Is there some trick to implementing the right thing correctly without nasty template code to check whether `T::operator new` exists?

Comment: You might want to check how an implementation of `std::vector` handles it. It should have the exact same problems.

Comment: It seems that libc++ doesn't try: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/vector, and Microsoft's implementation refuses: https://ofekshilon.com/2010/05/05/stdvector-of-aligned-elements/

Comment: the builtin `new` handlers call `::operator new` which produces memory guaranteed to be aligned for any type

Comment: @M.M sure, but I can't call `new T` directly, because I have constraints to construct the object separately from allocating the space it will live in.

Comment: @PhilMiller my comment applies to `new char[]`

Comment: `new char[]` does *not* return memory suitable for *over* aligned types, which I may have to handle. And, as noted, it's inappropriate for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to follow the same rules a [new-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) uses to determine the correct [allocation function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) to call, but I don't know any way off the top of my head to automatically produce that call.  It's fairly straightforward in principle (I think) to write the usual family of templates to detect when the class-specific overloads are/are not present and branch of `alignof(T) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` but I agree it's tedious.